# Need a gradient on the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, background, gradient

In the image below is the effect I want(notice the subtle green at the bottom of the screen). I also want to use it as multiple screens so I want it to be the background. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Can't you include the image as png?

Comment: No, that would look really bad on other devices, because of the stretching.

Answer (score 1):

Set the png as background, or create a shape in xml:

Create an xml file - let's call it "gradient_background.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient 
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#ff0000ff" 
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Change the hex color values to the ones you want.

and add it as background to your ViewGroup e.g. LinearLayout:

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
```

EDIT:
To achieve what you mentioned in your comment, that the gradient height should stay fixed while positioned at the bottom, but the white area can stretch vertically, I suggest you use a [nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) which you can create with the Draw Nine Patch [Tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html). Launch the tool from your SDK's tools folder - click the nine-patch bat file (and wait a while for it to launch, then import your png). You then draw black lines along the sides of your image to define which parts can be stretched, name the file something.9.png and reference it as background in your ViewGroup. Please see the linked-to documentation for details.

Comment: Well, i can't use a *.png, that would stretch on other devices and look really ugly. The second solution is the way i want to do it, but i need the gradient to start at the bottom of the screen. On a device with a 320*480 pixels for example, there should be white for the first 400 pixels, then the gradient should start at 400 until 480.